# How do I access model and controller attributes from inside application.html.erb?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, scope

I have a model an a controller for a pages resource.
I need to be able to access the names of the pages 
and the pages and link_to from within the
Application.html.erb

I have tried rendering a navigation partial. 
But you can't access the controller from a partial.
I need to be able to render a navbar that has access
the @pages variable so I can loop through them.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your ApplicationController, `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :get_pages

  protected

  def get_pages
    @pages ||= Page.all
  end

end
```

This way you're able to use the `@pages` instance variable from within any view.

By using memoization through the `||=` operator you're only assigning the variable the first time you need it, so no need to worry about calling that method every time.

Comment: Nicely done, even added variable caching there to make sure it only assigns its if it hasn't already been set. So will this work in the nav partial? A partials still a view right?

Comment: Right, this will work in any partial. That's the solution I've been using in my projects.

Comment: Glad to help. Just picking my answer as the correct one will be enough reward. :)